# How can I use a private Google Sheet as a database for my Android app?

Tags: android, google-sheets

I am developing an application for Android for an event which should present the user with the information of every speaker, such as name, age and profession.

I want to be able to have every speaker's information on a Google Sheet and make the app access to it. But I also want to make some of the information **private**, such as the speaker's phone number.

Is this possible or do I have to create one sheet with the public information, so that I can share the link and use it in the app?

Answer (score 0):

Do not publish information you don't want to publish.

I would create a shareable view on the sheet and share that, not anything that had private information in it.